# Mock a token for flask unit tests - firebase-admin-python SDK

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am using the firebase-admin-python SDK to handle authentication between an iOS app and a flask backend (python). This is my backend authentication endpoint, following [the firebase guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens):

```
from flask import request
from firebase_admin import auth


def get():
    """accessed via '/api/authtoken' """
    try:
        fir_token = request.headers["Authorization"]
        decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(fir_token)
        fir_auth_id = decoded_token["uid"]
    except:
        ...
```

How do I mock the fir_token for a unit test? How do I also mock `auth.verify_id_token` such that I don't need to actually connect to the firebase server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the logic behind an interface.

```
class TokenVerifier(object):
    def verify(self, token):
        raise NotImplementedError()


class FirebaseTokenVerifier(TokenVerifier):
    def verify(self, token):
        return auth.verify_id_token(token)


class MockTokenVerifier(TokenVerifier):
    def verify(self, token):
         # Return mock object that will help pass your tests.
         # Or raise an error to simulate token validation failures.
```

Then make sure during unit tests your code uses the `MockTokenVerifier`.

It is also possible to create mock ID tokens, and stub out parts of the Admin SDK so that the `auth.verify_id_token()` runs normally during tests (see [unit tests](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/blob/bbfa5e861cbb07b8e5a89195bb0dde5e72cd7e56/tests/test_token_gen.py#L76) of the SDK). But I prefer the above solution since it's easier, cleaner and doesn't require messing with the internals of the SDK.

Comment: Does this solution imply that I need to use `if config["TESTING"] == True:` before `decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(fir_token)` to toggle the `verifier`?

Comment: I don't know what `config` is. Generally speaking, how you swap the verifier during testing is really up to you. I'd recommend structuring your code in a way, so there's some module or class-level property that you can set to specify the verifier. Ideally, you shouldn't have to have conditionals in your `get()` request handler.

Answer (score 2):

I achieved this using the `patch` decorator from `unittest.mock` library.

**auth.py**

```py
...
from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse
from firebase_admin import auth

class Token(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        self.parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        self.parser.add_argument('token', type=str, required=True)

    # route for /api/auth/token
    def post(self):
        args = self.parser.parse_args()

        try:
            firebase_user = auth.verify_id_token(args['token'])
        except Exception:
            abort(401)

        # use firebase_user
```

**test_auth.py**

```py
from unittest import mock


mock_firebase_user = {
    'user_id': 'firebasegenerateduserid',
    'email': 'testuser@gmail.com',
    # ... add more firebase return values
}

# client is from conftest.py
def test_auth(client):
    with mock.patch('auth.auth.verify_id_token') as magic_mock:
        magic_mock.return_value = mock_firebase_user
        post_data = {
            'token': 'firebaserusertokenid'
        }

        response = client.post('/api/auth/token', data=post_data)
        assert response.status_code == 200
```

Comment: That's great, thank you! I had to use this for the patching though:

`mock.patch('firebase_admin.auth.verify_id_token') `